# Complex function mapping second sphere tangent to unit sphere

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Not sure about the question, please help correct it to convey properly or I could even delete if not meaningful.

The common intersecting  plane is through the north pole of top unit sphere. By Möbius  transformation we have stereographic mappings between small blue circles of top sphere through its north pole and  straight lines in the horizontal complex plane via the Möbius  transformation

$$ f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$

discussed for example in [Stereographic Projn/Moebius Transfrmn](https://www.maths.tcd.ie/%7Edwilkins/Courses/MA232A/MA232A_Mich2017/StWrapper.pdf). The geometrical connection appears to be through inversions/bipolar coordinates.

If now a second larger sphere is brought into mutual contact with its north pole, the complex plane and the south pole of the top unit sphere... can we have another complex function to describe the second set of small red circle mappings with the common tangent plane?

[image]

If so, could it belong to the same Möbius  group?

Comment: I see a first problem (that you have probly foreseen too) : there is a limit case beyond which the "blue" objects still exist whereas the "red" objects have no longer an existence... Is it compatible with the existence of a Möbius correpondence ?

Comment: I assume the black circles of your picture are cross-sections of spheres. You seem to be situating the complex plane at the *south* pole of the top sphere, not the north pole like you claim. Stereographic projection does indeed turn circles incident to the top sphere's north pole into lines in the complex plane, however the formula for stereographic projection is not a Mobius transformation (such transformations have the same domain/codomain, unlike projection). You seem to want a description of the red circles in the bottom sphere intersecting planes through the top sphere's north pole.

Comment: Thanks @ Jean Marie. Yes, saw that and sort of expected  the limit  could be modeled as part of new complex geometry.

Comment: Thanks @runway44: Yes, their meridians.The complex plane origin coincides with south pole of top sphere and north pole of bottom sphere. I included a link showing how the Moebius transformation and stereo projection are connected; me  yet to assimilate it. Extension to bottom of red circles in bottom sphere.. how may they come in is to be seen next ...